# Variable con sql server para generico

Tags: sql-server, select, variables

Estoy probando de hacer una función muy genérica para que me haga un `count` según las variables que le paso, este código ira dentro de un `function` donde le enviare las variables pero para hacer la prueba lo estoy haciendo así:

```
declare @taula nvarchar(20);
declare @pk nvarchar(20);
declare @valorCP nvarchar(20);
DECLARE @ext varchar(4000);
set @taula='empresa';
set @pk='CIF';
set @valorCP='1234567B';
set @ext ='select count(*) from '+@taula+' where '+@pk+'='''+@valorCP+''';';
print @ext;
EXEC sp_executesql @ext;
```

El `print` lo hace bien según lo que vaya cambiando pero el `EXEC` no me deja.
Seguro que alguien lo vera fácil, que estoy comenzando con el sql server.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: select count(*) from empresa where CIF=1234567B;                                        , he hecho un pequeño cambio en el codigo porque creo que va el ;

Comment: Intenta `set @ext ='select count(*) from '+@taula+' where '+@pk+'='''+@valorCP+''';';`

Comment: select count(*) from empresa where CIF='1234567';
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 234]
El procedimiento espera un parámetro '@statement' de tipo 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: es posible que @valorCP deba ser nvarchar

Comment: select count(*) from empresa where CIF='1234567B';
Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 234]
El procedimiento espera un parámetro '@statement' de tipo 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: El codigo lo he cambiado y ahora sale este error

Comment: El error indica que esta esperando un nvarchar en alguno de los campos y que le estas pasando un varchar. Prueba a modificar tambien @ext a nvarchar a ver si asi ya te funciona

Comment: Ya ha funcionado!!!! Muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow. El error se encuentra en el tipo de datos con el cual declaras tus variables, tal como lo indica, estos deben ser del siguiente tipo: `ntext/nchar/nvarchar`. Por lo cual, tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
declare @taula nvarchar(20);
declare @pk nvarchar(20);
declare @valorCP nvarchar(20);
DECLARE @ext nvarchar(4000);
set @taula='empresa';
set @pk='CIF';
set @valorCP='1234567B';
set @ext ='select count(*) from '+@taula+' where '+@pk+'='''+@valorCP+''';';
print @ext;
EXEC sp_executesql @ext;
```